# How to retrieve objects from a MySQL Database with a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, oop

I have 2 tables: **Document** and **Category** with a many to many relationships. In addition, the relationship has an attribute called *weight*.
I also have the corresponding Classes with **Document** being represented like this:

```
public class Document {
    private Integer id; // Id from DB, 0 if new object
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private List<Category> categories;

    // getters & setters...
    }
```

Now I have 2 questions - best practices concerns especially.
I want to retrieve data from the database (MySQL) and and build my objects. I use a SELECT statement like that:

```
SELECT doc.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.CategoryID SEPARATOR ',') AS CategoryGrp FROM document doc
LEFT JOIN doc_category dc ON doc.Doc_ID = dc.DC_DocID
LEFT JOIN category cat ON dc.DC_CategoryID = cat.CategoryID
GROUP BY doc.Doc_ID
```

In the resultset, **rs.getString(5) --> CategoryGrp** will have the IDs of the related categories. Now how do I proceed to build my object Document by linking its Categories as the Class requires it.

I tend to do new **SELECT** request on table **Category** to get the others details (category name for instance) in a loop while still on the first ResultSet.
Is that a good practice? Isn't there a "recommended" way?

My second question is about the attribute *weight* in junction table. In which object should I record its value? I guess it's Category but not very sure since Category object can't have a **weight** on its own...

Hope I have clear enough.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to 1st question:
2 ways: one sql or like you suggest 2 sql. (retriev the docs and for every cat id perform sql to retrive cat attributes)
I think this is better:
Get your all docs with different cats and its attributes. Loop it and compare the doc with the previous one. If different, then you have a new doc object. Every line in the loop is a different cat object.

```
doc1 cat1
doc1 cat2
doc1 cat3
doc2 cat4
doc3 cat5
doc3 cat6
...
```

Answer to 2nd question: 
I think you should consider this: is the weight more related to doc or cat? On the other hand, you cannot have multiple weights on 1 doc, so my guess would be to add the to cat (as that is a 1 on 1 relationship.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the best way to avoid all these loops would be using an ORM tool?

Comment: yes, you could use Hibernate and it will 'do' the loops for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relationship in RDBMS are *ALWAYS* done by at least 3 tables. So you need a third table, which will contain the ID`s from the first two, all of your SELECT-s will go through this third table.

Comment: I already have a 3rd table. My problem was an **efficient** way to retrieve the data and create my **Java objects** and still keep the relationships. I don't need 3 classes to do that: Just a composite/object attribute: Category - which is a Class that I created - in Class Document.

Take a look to my Class Document...